# How to set random numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to know how can I set the random number so that it’s between 1-10 and does not display decimals like 0.744545454? 
Also how can I iterate through each record through execution so that each row will contain its own random number for ‘PlayerWeighting?

Below Is my stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Player_CreateWholeTeam]
    @TeamID INT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(25)
        DECLARE @Surname VARCHAR(25)
        DECLARE @PlayerWeighting TINYINT

        SELECT @FirstName = TeamName  
        FROM dbo.Team 
        WHERE TeamID = @TeamID

        SELECT @Surname = 'Player' + cast(NumberID AS VARCHAR (10)) 
        FROM dbo.Team CROSS JOIN dbo.Number 
        WHERE TeamID = @TeamID 
        ORDER BY TeamID, NumberId

        SELECT @PlayerWeighting = RAND(1-10)
        FROM dbo.Player

    INSERT INTO dbo.Player (FirstName, Surname, PlayerWeighting, TeamID)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @Surname, @PlayerWeighting, @TeamID)


END
```

Comment: `FLOOR(RAND(10)) + 1`.  The second `SELECT` doesn't really make sense, because it looks like it would return multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, (RAND() * 10))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's simple code to generate a random number:

```
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT

---- This will create a random number between 1 and 999
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 999 ---- The highest random number
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random
```

You can put this into a function and then set the value to the result of that function if you want to do multiple rows.

If you want to use in a user defined function you have to create a view first because you can't use the RAND() function a UDF.

Here's an example of how to do that process:

```
-- View to be used in UDF
CREATE VIEW Get_RAND
AS
SELECT RAND() AS myRand

GO

--Simple UDF to get a random number
CREATE FUNCTION myRandom(@lower INT, @upper INT ) 
    RETURNS int
as

BEGIN

DECLARE @Random INT;

---- This will create a random number between @lower and @upper   
DECLARE @RAND DECIMAL(10,10) = (SELECT myRand FROM Get_RAND)
set @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * @RAND + @Lower), 0)
RETURN @Random

END

-- Use of the function
SELECT dbo.myRandom(1, 100)
```

Comment: Is it ok if you show me an example of creating a function if you don't mind please?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Player_CreateWholeTeam]
    @TeamID INT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Player (FirstName, Surname, PlayerWeighting, TeamID)
SELECT  TeamName as Firstname,
        'Player' + cast(NumberID AS VARCHAR (10))  as Surname , 
        FLOOR(RAND(Checksum(NEWID()))*(10-1)+1)     as PlayerWeighting ,
        @TeamID  as TeamID
        FROM dbo.Team  CROSS JOIN dbo.Number 
        WHERE TeamID = @TeamID
End
```

Replace Your procedure code as above. I am inserting records directly from the result of select queries. Select query is made combining the existing queries. The select query will help insering random player weighting for each player

Comment: If that select statement returns more than one row, they will all have the same random number.  The `RAND()` call is expanded as a scalar constant.

Comment: @matbailie I have placed my random number logic inside a function. Now it will generate different number for each row

Comment: You should test that.  I believe that even your function is expanded as a scalar constant, as it only has scalar constant inputs.  The general "trick" is to use NEWID, or something similar, as an input to ensure there are no constant inputs.

Comment: @MatBailie I removed the function and added seed to rand function. now it generates different value for each row